# Vue devServer proxy is not helping, I still get CORS error

Tags: vue.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server, vue-cli-3

I'm using @vue/cli 3.x and in my vue.config.js I have this:

```
devServer: {
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        ws: true,
        changeOrigin: true,
        target: "http://localhost:8080"
      }
    }
  }
```

But I keep getting CORS error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api' from origin
>   'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Any idea?

Comment: I'm no CORS expert, but if I were to guess I'd say you need to enable CORS from your server and add Access-Control-Allow-Origin to your request header. It's your server complaining, not your Vue frontend.

Comment: @JamesWhiteley - that is exactly why I define a proxy, so I don't need to define CORS on my server

Comment: @Tomer: did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @dotNET - actually yes :), apparently I had some Axios configurations that were ignoring the proxy. my dev server config looks like this: 
`devServer: {
    proxy: {
      "^/api": {
        target: url,
        ws: true,
        changeOrigin: true
      }
    }
  },`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like the problem was with the axios configurations.

I had this definition: `axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:8080/api";`
I changed it to `axios.defaults.baseURL = "api";`

and it works.

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    devServer: {
        proxy: {
          "^/api": {
          target: url,
          ws: true,
          changeOrigin: true
        }
     }
  },
}
```

Comment: In what file do you exactly add this `axios.defaults.baseURL = "api"` ?

Comment: I have axios.config.js file which i import in my main file, but it doesn't really matter what you name it

Comment: Yup, this was very useful. Thanks a lot