# CORS policy in vue.js. Access only in backend?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

If I have project in `vue-cli` with no `node.js` (or `express.js`), can I somehow unblocke this `CORS` access? 
I tried to add a code in `vue.config.js`

`vue.config.js`:

```
       module.exports = {
        devServer: {
         proxy: {
         '/api': {
         target: 'http://18.700.121.3:8000/',
          ws: true,
         changeOrigin: true
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

`vue template`

```
 import axios from 'axios'
  export default {
   name: "Jokes",
  data () {
  return {
    songs: null,
  }
 },
 },
   mounted () {
    const config = {headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}};
    axios
    .get(`http://2.788.121.2:4000/`, config) //it a sample api
    .then(
        response => (
            this.songs= response.data))
   }

}
</script>
```

but it didn't help. Also I tried to swich-on chrome plugin `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, where I add access to `localhost:8080`, but still doesnt work. 
So it is possible, that only option is install node.js and add res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","*");

Comment: add this to the devServer config?

Comment: I add this part code to vue.config.js. But this res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","*") I did't add, because I read it should be on backend side.

Comment: DevServer is backend

Comment: Ok, but I dont have node.js and express.js, so it os possible to do something to on the frontend side? Or only install express

Comment: Wait - vue-cli without nodejs? Does this actually work? Basically any server is fine - eg nginx apache etc just point to the dist folder (index.html))

Comment: CORS should be added in the app which receives/process the request, not the one who sends the requests. Clarify which app process the requests and which app sends the request or if both are same app.

Comment: ok I am a newbe in this backend things. I install a vue-cli and do all js scripts and scss layouts. I havn't bahd a problem with this CORS. I know vue is on node.js but i really dont't know where exactly I should add this  `res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","*")`. I have only main.js, babel.config.js and vue.config.js files.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55607326/vue-devserver-proxy-is-not-helping-i-still-get-cors-error maybe this is your issue?

Comment: I add some more code to my question where exactly I tried to get access to this api.

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a **response** header - don't put it in a **request** - CORS is up to the **server** ... i.e. `2.788.121.2` needs to respond with CORS headers if the request is not same origin -

Comment: The code you added to `vue.config.js` means that the dev server will proxy any unknown requests (requests that did not match a static file) that match `/api` to `18.700.121.3` ... is this your server? This one does NOT need to send CORS response headers. Anyway, the request to `2.788.121.2` is just made directly to that ip address and the proxy setting you made has no impact on it at all - so it will need to allow CORS access

Comment: I changed the ip, to not show it nobody.. I get it form other company to get the data from api and do some simple tasks.. and I can not do this, because of this access :/ I'm quite frustrated.

Comment: so you cant change the api server response header - thus you can for developement e.g. proxy pass it to a local ip with something that doesnt care about cors and add cors header - there should be plenty of solutions on SO ... or use a browser that doesnt care about cors

Comment: yeeee, I change to a firefox and switch on the plugin. Thanks for helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try remove the header `const config = {headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}};` from the request

The additional header will just confuse the browser

Answer (score 0):

First way,
Use Cors Plugin in chrome Eg- Moseif CORS or Degrade your chrome version less than 71.

Second way, If you can modify the server-side code (If using express)

Add below codes, You can easily solved this problem.

```
var cors = require('cors')

var app = express()
app.use(cors())
```

Answer (score -3):

1. Close the Chrome.
2. Hold down the Windows Key and Press R on your keyboard. The "RUN" dialog box will open.
3. Insert the following input field `chrome --disable-web-security --user-data-dir` and run it
4. Now run your vue.js app

Hope it helps.

Comment: now don't browse anything on the internet as your browser is wide open to all manner of nasties

Comment: how can I swich off this?

Comment: close the browser and open it. It will open in usual form.